# How do I fill a va_list

Tags: c, variadic-functions

If I have a va_list I know how to extract all its elements:

```
void printInts(int n,...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, n);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int arg=va_arg(va, int);
        printf("%d",arg);
    }
    va_end(va);
}
```

So when I call printInts(3,1,2,3) the va_list get filled of all the parameters.
But how do I manually fill a va_list without using va_start? I mean that I want something like:

```
va_list va;
push_arg(va, int, 5); // And so on until I fill all parameters
...
```

I need this because there is a function that accept a va_list as argument, and I don't know how to fill that va_list of all its parameters.

Comment: The type `va_list` isn't actually a list as such, it's actually often a kind of a pointer to the stack, and `va_arg` modifies this pointer to point to the next argument on the stack.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Sometimes it's not a pointer to the stack.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `va_start`?

Comment: Because I need a raw va_list with all it's argument, I need to do the opposite thing than va_start-va_arg-va_end .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's no ability to fill a va_list explicitly.

You should write a wrapper function. Say you need to call your function foo, instead of manually filling in a va_list, you define a new function like so:

```
void call_foo(int arg1, ...)
{
   va_list ap;
   va_start(ap, arg1);
   foo(arg1, ap);
   va_end(ap);
}
```

Now you can call `foo`, which takes a va_list, however you like, by doing e.g. call_foo(1,2,3,4);, call_foo(1, 1, "Hello"); etc.

This will only allow you to specify the arguments at compile time, you can't build the arguments at runtime.

Answer (score 13):

Normally, these functions come in pairs. If you have a "va-accepting" function, it is easy to create another one:

```
void printInts_v(int n, va_list ap)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int arg=va_arg(ap, int);
        printf("%d", arg);
    }
}
```

This function can be called this way:

```
void printInts(int n,...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, n);
    printInts_v(n, ap);
    va_end(va);
}
```

But I don't think there is a way to portably pre-fill a `va_list` for later use.

If you work on one architecture and portability is not an issue, you could craft something on your own, however. How exactly to do that is platform-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standardized way of doing this. On the other hand, such a pre-filled `va_list` would be pretty useless, since there's no way of "querying" it for the number and types of available arguments, either.

Comment: I think the question is like "how do I call `vprintf()`?" and the answer is "write `printf()` and call it from there".

Comment: There is a function of a framework that accepts a va_list, how do I go around this?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri As written in - up to now - two answers.

Comment: @glglgl: (I know this is quite an old question but) none of those answers are usable. because they all assume you know the argument list at compile time. The real problem, is about building the va_list dynamically.

Comment: @Camion That cannot be done, at least not in portable standard C, which is what the answers are saying.

Comment: @unwind, what the answers say is that there is no portable way to build a va_list. Ramy AlZuhouri's question glglgl was replying was about the possibility of a work around solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since other replies tells it's impossible (which would be a good reason to add it in the design of the language for the next version), The only portable possibility would be

- to check the documentation twice to investigate if you didn't miss or
  misunderstand something about the framework you're trying to use : I
  had the exact same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987022/when-extending-python-with-c-how-do-one-dynamically-build-a-complex-structure-i) and it appeared in the answer
  that I was not using the right call for what I was trying to do;
- to write yourself a function which would take an array of pointers as parameter instead of the va_list and  split the problem in multiple calls (not always possible); or
- assume the framework you're trying to use was poorly designed...

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the function into multiple calls works for the *printf* family - there is code for this in Kernighan & Ritchie, along the lines of:

```
void printf_OclFile(struct OclFile* self, char* f, void* sq[])
{ int n = length(sq);
  if (n == 0 || self->actualFile == NULL) 
  { return; }

  void* ap; 
  char* p = f; 
  int i = 0; 

  char* sval; 
  int ival; 
  double dval; 

  ap = sq[0]; 
  for ( ; *p != '\0' && i < n; p++)
  { if (*p != '%')
    { char* p0 = subString(p,1,1); 
      fputs(p0, self->actualFile); 
      continue; 
    } 

    p++; /* Points to flag after % */ 

    switch (*p)
    { case 'd' : 
        ival = *((int*) sq[i]); 
        i++; 
        fprintf(self->actualFile, "%d", ival);
        break; 
      case 'f' : 
        dval = *((double*) sq[i]); 
        i++; 
        fprintf(self->actualFile, "%f", dval); 
        break; 
      case 's' : 
        sval = ((char*) sq[i]); 
        i++; 
        fprintf(self->actualFile, "%s", sval); 
        break;
      default : 
        char* p0 = subString(p,1,1); 
        fputs(p0, self->actualFile);
        break; 
    }
  } 
}
```