# When extending Python with C, How do one dynamically build a complex structure in C?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, variadic-functions

I'd like to make a C function which returns a list of tuples, a list of dicts or even better, a list of objects of a class I defined in another python module.

The documentation on the C API («The Python/C API») mentions that to build a complex object, I need to call to `Py_BuildValue` which uses a Variable number of parameters or `Py_VaBuildValue` which uses a `va_list` argument.

Since C cannot dynamically make a call with a variable number of arguments, I cannot use `Py_BuildValue` and must use `Py_VaBuildValue`, but looking for how to build a `va_list` variable, I find replies which the [There's no ability to fill a va_list explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703891/9077457) and [tells me to make it from a variable parameters function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13703840/9077457), which defeats the purpose... and from the tests a made, all I get is segmentation faults and core dumps.

So, how am I Supposed to use those functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supposed to use those functions to build dynamically-sized data structures. The [FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/extending.html?highlight=py_buildvalue#how-do-i-use-py-buildvalue-to-create-a-tuple-of-arbitrary-length) says to use PyTuple_Pack instead of Py_BuildValue for an arbitrary-sized tuple, but that's wrong too; I don't know why it says that. PyTuple_Pack has the same varargs issues as Py_BuildValue.

To build a variable-length tuple from C, use [`PyTuple_New`](http://PyTuple_New) to construct an uninitialized tuple of the desired length, then loop over the indices and set the elements with [`PyTuple_SET_ITEM`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SET_ITEM). Yes, this mutates the tuple. `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` is *only* safe to use to initialize fresh tuples that have not yet been exposed to other code. Also, be aware that `PyTuple_SET_ITEM` steals a reference to the new element.

For example, to build a tuple of integers from 0 to n-1:

```
PyObject *tup = PyTuple_New(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Note that PyTuple_SET_ITEM steals the reference we get from PyLong_FromLong.
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(tup, i, PyLong_FromLong(i));
}
```

To build a variable-length list from C, you can do the same thing with `PyList_New` and `PyList_SET_ITEM`, or you can construct an empty list with `PyList_New(0)` and append items with `PyList_Append`, much like you would use `[]` and `append` in Python if you didn't have list comprehensions or sequence multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, it works (except for the bugs in my code ;-) ). Do you know how I should proceed to make my C extension return an object from class defined in a python's module ?

Comment: @Camion: Same way you'd do it in Python. Retrieve the class object and perform a [function call](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Call).