# How to initialize a va_list object in c++?

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

## This is getting annoying

I was long enough trying to fix this, but i have to ask you how to fix this because I have no ideas anymore.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

void add(const int &number, ...)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    va_list list;

    va_start(list, number);
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        sum += va_arg(list, double);

    va_end(liste);

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}

int main()
{
    add(12, 12);
}
```

This is my code. I get the error, that `list` ist not initiaized and i get the error, that  the `va_start` argument must not have reference type and it must not be parenthesized. pls help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fill a va\_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703770/how-do-i-fill-a-va-list)

Comment: The main problem is that you call the `add` function with two *integer* values. More specifically two `int` values. I don't know any system where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(double)`, which means you will have *undefined behavior* in the `add` function.

Comment: No reproduction, `list` is initialized (or rather filled) prior to use here. There is a  typo in `va_end(liste);` though and types of arguments passed are not matching extracted values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your version, you're supposed to first pass the number of arguments as an integer value and then pass `double` values (since you interpret them as `double`). Passing `int` and interpreting as `double` as in your example causes undefined behavior. Here's the fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

void add(int count, ...) 
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    std::va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        sum += va_arg(args, double);
    }
    va_end(args);

    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    add(4, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0);
}
```

Here's a type-safe solution which works even if you mix `int`s and `double`s:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
void add(Args... args)
{
  std::cout << (args + ...) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    add(25.0, 25, 25.0, 25);
}
```